# JQBARGRAPH php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, bar-chart

i want to ask how come my barchart is not rendering. The bar was dont have any color..as I found from the document , it just need jquery and don't need any css to stye it. Any idea??

```
    <div id='barchart'></div>
    <script>
        arrayOfData = new Array(
             [<?php echo $notification->get_module_activity_count($user_id,'employee');?>,'Employee'],
             [<?php echo $notification->get_module_activity_count($user_id,'bulletin');?>,'Bulletin'],
             [<?php echo $notification->get_module_activity_count($user_id,'filesharing');?> ,'FileSharing'],
             [<?php echo $notification->get_module_activity_count($user_id,'login');?> ,'Login']
        );

        $('#barchart').jqbargraph({
             data: arrayOfData,
            colors: ['#666','#000']
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in the console/firebug?

Comment: hmm,nope ,dont show any error on console log @@ thats i wondering whats the problem >.<

Comment: Your initialization looks good. Maybe the php function don't return a well structured data. Check the source file! Is the arrayOfData well-formed?

Comment: You're giving it four bars to render in arrayOfData, but only two colors in the config. Maybe that is your problem

Comment: hmm, actually i did tried on the sample code they provide, it dont work also, i do see whats the output of my php function return, it output me number. The color i follow the documentation which just got 2 colors

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? And what version of jqbargraph are you using?

Comment: jquery-1.8.0.min.js....compatible/?

Comment: Hard to say... The official site states that the plugin is tested with with jQ 1.3, and there's a version of the plugin for jQ 1.4, but nothing for 1.8. Why don't you test it with an older version of jQuery and give yourself an answer? :)